# PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile Header/Footer Issue

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

Created a phonegap application using jQuery Mobile. Everything is working great for the most part, accept for the persistent header and footer bars. They disappear when clicking or scrolling. The position of them also screws up quite often. I would love to figure out how to fix this. Let me know if there is any code I can paste.

Also, is there anything specific with CSS I need to do?

I have also tried using: $.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false); with no success. Is there a specific place I should place it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iScroll` javascript plugin which will make your header and footer with the fixed position and your inner div tag will be scrollable.
You can find iScroll lib here- http://cubiq.org/iscroll

You can also think about `JQTouch` lib (http://jqtouch.com/) which all ready has some nice css.

if you want to used JQTouch and iScroll together, you can find useful code here- https://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch

Demo - http://web.me.com/djpinter1/iPhone/jqtouch/demos/main_tabbar/#ui

thanks,
Mayur

Comment: In iOS 5 you can use position:fixed; on header and footer!

Comment: Without using another plugin, such as iScroll, I was unable to fix it. I switched from PhoneGap to Titanium Mobile. Much better!

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in your document ready and it will disable disappearing when clicking and scrolling

```
$("[data-role=header]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
$("[data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
```

Best of luck